# How to write the address of a house that consists of several numbered buildings

Tags: translation, correspondence

I'm translating a Russian document in which there is the following address (literally from Russian):

> 107076, Moscow, Korolenko Street, House 2 Building 6

That is, House 2 consists of several standalone buildings, and we write to someone in Building 6. We write this as "house" in Russian, but in reality it might be called 'complex of houses' in English, probably.

I know that we usually write the number of the house before the street name in English. But how to put that "building 6" into that?

Would this do:

> 107076, Moscow, 2/6 Korolenko Street

.. or is there some other way?

P.S. The original Russian sentence is:

> 107076, г. Москва, ул. Короленко, дом 2 стр. 6

Comment: In the US it would be *2 Korolenko Street, Bldg #6, Moscow 107076*  (and for "bldg" you might see "Unit" instead).

Comment: I think your question is about address format conventions, not learning English. From the translation POV, why not just translate it without changing the format? The format someone would expect to be normal will depend on where the reader is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are to go the correct way *(as given in different source like [Linguistic Services Inc.](http://pinsonlingo.com/blog/?p=102))* then it should be either:

- 107076, Moscow, ul. Korolenko, d. 2, str. 6
- House 2, Building 6, Korolenko st., Moscow, 107076

Or as some sources indicate "**строение**" as "**building**" (or **bldg**) and, I as a native Russian speaker can prove that the translation is correct. So it's possible to write the address the other way:

- 107076, Moscow, Korolenko st. 2, bldg 6

It is also correct to translate it these ways:

- 107076, Moscow, Ulitsa Korolenko 2, stroenie 6
- 2 Korolenko St., Building 6, Moscow, 107076 - *(or Bldg 6)*

**McQwen** is also correct about the order **Room/Apartment/Home, Building, Street, City/Town/Village, County, Postcode/ZIP Code**

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you'd write an address in tiered order, so;

> Room/Apartment/Home, Building, Street, City/Town/Village, County, Postcode/ZIP Code

So the address from your example would be like so if it were a British or American address;

> House 2, Building 6, Korolenko Street, Moscow, 107076

And the address for the head office of the BBC is;

> BBC London, Broadcasting House, Egton Wing, Portland Place, London, W1A 1AA

People sometimes also add the country to the end of the address, either before or after the Postcode/ZIP code, but that's typically only if the item is being sent abroad.

Comment: Thank you! But would it look okay to a native speaker, I mean, "House 2, Building 6", or would it be better to use "Unit" or "Lot" in place of "House"?

Comment: @CowperKettle Tᴚoɯɐuo's comment has the best answer for US cases. I have also seen "Entrance" (подъезд) added, as follows: 2 Korolenko Street, Bldg #6, Entrance X, Moscow 107076. In the US, numbers are always given first, then street name, then unit, apartment, or suite).